# Filter Many2one field - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I know I can filter `Many2one` fields, from python code, or even xml views, with the `domain` flag, but I have a slightly different scenario right now,

Consider having a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'mymodel'

    fieldsel = fields.Selection([('sheet', 'Sheet'),('reel','Reel')], string='Printing PPT Type', 
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")
    fieldmany = fields.Many2one('text.paper', string="Text Paper")
```

The `text.paper` model has another Selection field, which has the same values as `fieldsel`, however, I cannot use `domain` since it will filter every `text.paper` statically.

My issue is, that I need to filter `text.paper` depending on which option I choose from `fieldsel`, so, let's say `text.paper` looks something like this:

```
class text_paper(models.Model):
    _name = 'text.paper'

    name = fields.Char(string="Code")
    paper_type = fields.Selection([('sheet', 'Sheet'),('reel','Reel')], string="Paper Type")
```

I need to filter from `mymodel` the `text.paper` depending on the `fieldsel` field, if reel selected, filter `text.paper` which are reel, and if sheet selected, filter `text.paper` accordingly.

I hope I've explained myself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is dynamic domain for many2one you can achive this by onchange event

```py
    class MyModel(models.Model):
        _name = 'mymodel'

        ....
        ...

        @api.onchange('fieldsel ')
        def change_domain(self):
            """change the domain of fieldmany  whenever the user changes the selected value."""
            self.fieldmany = False # may be you want to reset the value when the user changes the selected value
            if self.fieldsel : # make sure the user has selected a value
                return {'domain': {fieldmany: [('paper_type', '=', self.fieldsel)]}}
            else: # remove domain 
                return {'domain': {fieldmany: []}}
```

Comment: Here to help @NeoVe remember when you deal with dynamic domains you have two choice for simple one oncange is enough but some times you will need to override the `name_search` method because it's the function that many2one field calls to filter the record.

Comment: Cool, Great to know, Thank You!